# CSS :not(img){ background-color : $c ;...} img{ background-color:transparent ;...} works on SOME pages, not all, with chrome - why?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have installed a 'Developer Mode' Extension in latest chrome-dev / google-chrome-unstable
which consists only of the files:
'~/.config/google-chrome-unstable/User StyleSheets/Custom.css' (and the 'manifest.json' that lists it) :

```
*{
    color:#FFF !important;
    background-color:#000 !important;
}


A{
    color: #AEC ! important;
}

A:visited{
    color: #A9E ! important;
}
    
A:hover{
    color: #F0F ! important;
}
```

I also tried this better version :

```
button,select,form,table{
    color:#FFF !important;
    background-color:#213 !important;
}

img{
    background-color:transparent !important;
}

:not(img):not(button):not(select):not(form):not(table){
    color:#FFF !important;
    background-color:#000 !important;
}


A{
    color: #AEC ! important;
}

A:visited{
    color: #A9E ! important;
}
    
A:hover{
    color: #F0F ! important;
}
```

This works well to convert 99% of all webpages to a black background with white text,
including input forms, etc; and I am TRYING to allow background images to display
with only their default background (usually white) transparent-ed .

But with very few web-pages, such as 'workspaces.google.com/dashboard', and actually for
instance the 'Format Buttons' on this website, IMG button icon images
display as all black.

The URL and quoting HTML for one such image is in the 'Apps' list on the above
Google WorkSpaces URL :

```
&lt;div class="VfPpkd-EScbFb-JIbuQc" tabindex="0" jsname="hlMCCc" jscontroller="tKHFxf" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; 
&lt;div class="VfPpkd-EScbFb-JIbuQc" tabindex="0" jsname="hlMCCc" jscontroller="tKHFxf" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ;

mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc; touchcancel:JMtRjd; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;"&gt;

&ltimg class="prcjje" src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/productlogos/calendar_2020q4/v11/web-64dp/logo_calendar_2020q4_color_2x_web_64dp.png" data-atf="true" data-iml="772.3000000119209"&gt;
&lt;div class="QmXg0b"&gt;&lt;div class="sAmkAe" jsname="oT6k3d"&gt;Calendar&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="VfPpkd-FJ5hab"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;/div&gt;mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc; touchcancel:JMtRjd; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;"
&gt;img class="prcjje" src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/productlogos/calendar_2020q4/v11/web-64dp/logo_calendar_2020q4_color_2x_web_64dp.png" data-atf="true" data-iml="772.3000000119209"&gt;
&lt;div class="QmXg0b"&gt;&lt;div class="sAmkAe" jsname="oT6k3d"&gt;Calendar&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="VfPpkd-FJ5hab"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;

&lt;img class="prcjje" src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/productlogos/calendar_2020q4/v11/web-64dp/logo_calendar_2020q4_color_2x_web_64dp.png" data-atf="true" data-iml="772.3000000119209"&gt;
```

So the result is I can't see ANYTHING EXCEPT BLACK for ALL 'Apps' Icons,
no text alternative is displayed, I am carefully trying to exclude
images from having their background-color or color set, I can replace
'!img' with '*' and totally remove the 'img { }' clause in the CSS above
and almost the same result happens, except that images have white background -
but not the ones on the WorkSpaces dashboard!

What is it about above CSS that is making the icons on the WorkSpaces dashboard,
and on the Format Button Icons on this page for that matter, display as all black
(no image, no different background, just black) ?

[Site with 2nd Custom.css above installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOJCY.png)

[default Chrome New Window, showing IMGs OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wRZy.png)

What is even worse, is with ANY version of
${PROFILE}/User\ Stylesheets/Custom.css
installed, this page :
https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9389764
flashes displayably briefly, then disappears altogether
(the whole page is blank) .

Occurs with latest version of Custom.css :

```
body:not(img){
    background-color:#000 !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

:not(input):not(button):not(img):not(table):not(form):not(a){
    background-color:transparent !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

input{
    background-color:#444 !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

table{
    background-color:transparent !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

form{
    background-color:#111 !important;
    color:#FFF !important;    
}

button{
   background-color:#214 !important;
}

A{
    color: #AEC ! important;
}

A:visited{
    color: #A9E ! important;
}
    
A:hover{
    color: #F0F ! important;
}
```

and also visiting 'nasa.gov' displays no images on front page - strange, in above css I should not be affecting IMG tags at all.

OK, in response to editor's comment to make this question have
a simple reproducable example, see:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1335663

T.HTML v(A) :

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>
      Bug 1335663 Test Page
    </TITLE>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
      .wbgi{background-image:url("https://nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/2x2_cardfeed/public/thumbnails/image/nasa_meatball_large.jpg");
        width:740px;
        height:700px;
        align:center;
        text-align:center;
           }      
    </STYLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <FIGURE>
    <DIV class="wbgi">
      <H2> A Background Image</H2>
    </DIV>
      <FIGCAPTION>
    An Image displayed as Background Image in the same way it is on NASA's home page (thanks NASA!).
      </FIGCAPTION>
    </FIGURE>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Displays in Chrome, with Either of these

```
  ${PROFILE}/User\ StyleSheets/Custom.css
```

installed in about:extensions -> 'Enable Developer Mode'
-> 'Load Unpacked', with the manifest.json:

```
{ "name": "my_custom_css",
  "version": "1",
  "content_scripts": [{ "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*","file://*/*"],
            "css":     ["Custom.css"]
             }],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Custom.css v(A):

```
 
:not(img){
    background-color:#000 !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

A{
    color: #AEC ! important;
}

A:visited{
    color: #A9E ! important;
}
    
A:hover{
    color: #F0F ! important;
}
```

```
OR, like Version B:
```

```
body:not(img){
    background-color:#000 !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

:not(input):not(button):not(img):not(table):not(form):not(a){
    background-color:transparent !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

input{
    background-color:#444 !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

table{
    background-color:transparent !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

form{
    background-color:#111 !important;
    color:#FFF !important;    
}

button{
   background-color:#214 !important;
}

A{
    color: #AEC ! important;
}

A:visited{
    color: #A9E ! important;
}
    
A:hover{
    color: #F0F ! important;
}
```

v(B) of T.HTML is where its HEAD script section is extended
to include extant v(B) of Custom.css.

So, if that extension is enabled, with EITHER of the above v(A) or v(B) Custom.css files installed, Chrome displays T.HTML v(A) like:

[image: Chrome display of T.HTML with v(B) Custom.css AND NO in inclusion of Custom.css in HEAD style section]

(a black screen, no image displayed, white text and caption is shown).

Chrome displays T.HTML v(B), which repeats extant the installed
Custom.css in its HEAD -> STYLE section:

[image: Chrome View of T.HTML with Custom.css Version (B) installed, which repeats Custom.css v(B) in HEAD style section]

(a blank white screen, no text or image shown)

Firefox Display of EITHER version of T.HTML, with
default 'Dark' Theme selected, and the setting
'NEVER replace web-page colors with my colors' in effect,
showing the inline   inclusion
of v(B) Custom.css:

[image: firefox showing same T.HTML as in 2nd chrome screenshot above]

Comment: `!img,!button,!select,!form,!table` -> These are not valid CSS selectors...

Comment: I did not have those in until a few minutes ago, trying to fix this problem - will update issue with previous tested version that has same result.

Comment: A lot to unpack here.

Comment: yes, sorry, that Google HTML is impossible to dsiplay correctly in '```' code sections !  I can append whole html file if you are interested & cannot access Google WorkSpaces.

Comment: But same issue occurs ALSO WITH fORMAT BUTTONS on stackoverflow ,
so if you are in the Edit Question dialog, and have EITHER of  my Custom.css files above installed , the format buttons are invisible.

Comment: Please see updated CSS - the selection SHOULD be :

:not(img):not(button):not(select):not(form):not(table)


(no commas!)

Comment: The first image shows what the WorkSpaces dashboard window looks like
with my 2nd Custom.css file installed ( it looks very similar with the first one installed).

Comment: The second image shows what 'www.google.com' looks like, with 2nd CSS file,
showing that images are displayed OK with a TRANSPARENT background .

Comment: My question is: what is so different about the IMG files loaded from WorkSpaces that they do not display .

Comment: And now with 2nd Custom.css file installed as above, the Format Buttons in stackoverflow Edit Question now appear as Text - no images - but at least I can see them now .

Comment: OK, the 3rd, working version of my Custom.css DOES color all background 
images black - even though it mentions neither the background-image CSS 
attribute nor the 'img' tag as a selector - none of its selectors should select 'IMG' tags, and none of its rules specify anything about background-image, yet background images are not being displayed.

Comment: I think this is a BUG with chrome-unstable (Chrome-Dev) .

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: OK, this issue now is simply reproducible by loading the example 'T.HTML' file
into latest Chrome Beta with either version of my Custom.css extension installed.

Answer (score 2):

OK , this really does appear to be a chrome bug:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1335663

I can't see how a Custom.css file of this CSS:

```
body:not(img){
    background-color:#000 !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

:not(input):not(button):not(img):not(table):not(form):not(a){
    background-color:transparent !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

input{
    background-color:#444 !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

table{
    background-color:transparent !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

form{
    background-color:#111 !important;
    color:#FFF !important;    
}

button{
   background-color:#214 !important;
}

A{
    color: #AEC ! important;
}

A:visited{
    color: #A9E ! important;
}
    
A:hover{
    color: #F0F ! important;
}
```

affects the display of 'background-image's at all,
nor why its effect should be identical to that of
this Custom.css:

```
:not(img){
    background-color:#000 !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

A{
    color: #AEC ! important;
}

A:visited{
    color: #A9E ! important;
}
    
A:hover{
    color: #F0F ! important;
}
```

, but it is! At least in the version of Chrome I am using ...
that in itself is a bug - it is not honoring CSS correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, Finally a Version of Custom.css that works with Chrome,
allowing background images to be displayed ! :

```
html,body,canvas{
    color:#FFF !important;
    background-color:#000 !important;
}

button,select,form,table{
    color:#FFF !important;
    background-color:#213 !important;
}

input{
    color:#FFF !important;
    background-color:#444 !important;
}

img{
    background-color:transparent !important;
}


A{
    color: #AEC ! important;
}

A:visited{
    color: #A9E ! important;
}
    
A:hover{
    color: #F0F ! important;
}


:not(button):not(select):not(form):not(table):not(input):not(body):not(canvas):not(img):not(a){
    color:#FFF !important;
    background-color:transparent !important;
}
```

OK, I still think this version SHOULD BE functionally
identical to the v(B) Custom.css shown in previous comments
on Chrome as it is on Firefox, I still think my previous
answer is correct that it is a bug in Chrome that this is
not the case, but at last I have found a workaround that
works to color the web white-foreground-on-black-background
while allowing background images to be displayed with chrome.

Perhaps a CSS guru could enlighten me as to a valid CSS reason
why this CSS works to display background images in chrome, while
previous versions did not.

Comment: And if you also enable the 'chrome://flags' setting : \
  Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents
Automatically render all web contents using a dark theme. – Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, Android, Fuchsia, Lacros

#enable-force-dark


Then auto-dark applies to chrome: URLs, while your Custom.css applies to web.